# Optimal instrument in panel IV

Tags: instrumental-variables

I am estimating demand elasticity in panel data instrumenting log price with a cost variable. I have 3 versions of the model:

1. In which I used the cost variable directly
2. In which I used a log of the cost variable as an instrument
3. In which I used both the log of the cost variable and the cost variable itself

All three versions have similar standard errors, but the obtained coefficients differ a lot. How should I choose one?

Comment: How do coefficients differ, in the first or second stage?

Comment: @ChristophHanck The estimate in front of price in the second stage differs, that is what I was descriing. In the first stage when I put them both, the level cost variable is not significant.